# Why is SQL Server choosing the "wrong" Index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have a Transaction table with about 200 million records, one primary key clustered on Id and 2 indexes:

- IX_SiloId_ChangedTime_IncludeTime
- IX_SiloId_Time_IncludeContent

I run these 2 statements before I proceed with the actual query to update statistics

```sql
Update STATISTICS dbo.[Transaction] IX_SiloId_ChangedTime_IncludeTime WITH FULLSCAN
Update STATISTICS dbo.[Transaction] IX_SiloId_Time_IncludeContent WITH FULLSCAN
```

This is my query:

```sql
DECLARE @Query SiloTimeQueryTableType -- (SiloId, Time) with primary key clustered on SiloId
INSERT INTO @Query VALUES 
(1, '2020-12-31'), -- 1000 total values, though it's still the same problem with just one

SELECT  t.*
FROM    [Transaction] t
INNER JOIN @Query q
    ON t.SiloId = q.SiloId
WHERE 
    t.Time >= q.Time
```

Now what happens is for whatever reason Sql Server choses `IX_SiloId_ChangedTime_IncludeTime`. It then takes forever. If I use `WITH (INDEX(IX_SiloId_Time_IncludeContent))` I get the result right away.

The correct index is quite obvious here, but yet SQL Server choses the one that is not even indexed on Time.

I cannot understand this behaviour, but from what I read it is best to avoid hints for Indexes, though I made this Index with this query in mind.

So the question is: what can I do to try to figure out why SQL Server prefers the "wrong" index even though a much better one exists and I just run full statistics update?

I have created an temporary table as many suggest that TVP fails, but the result is the same:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Query
(
    SiloId bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Time datetime2(7) NOT NULL
)
```

Execution plans:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJOt3G00P

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByFshGAAP (this one is live, as it takes too long)

Indices:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SiloId_Time_IncludeContent] ON [dbo].[Transaction]
(
    [SiloId] ASC,
    [Time] ASC
)
INCLUDE([SiloContent]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SiloId_ChangedTime_IncludeTime] ON [dbo].[Transaction]
(
    [SiloId] ASC,
    [ChangedTime] ASC
)
INCLUDE([Time]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Why are you posting the same question to both SO and DBA? And I see you deleted your previous question on the same topic where the use of a tvp / table variable was discussed.

Comment: Table variables don't have statistics, this might be the reason why SQL Server chooses the wrong index. I suggest you to use a temporal table instead and see if in this case SQL Server Server chooses the right index

Comment: @SMor because these are 2 different sites with different people answering apparently?

Comment: @JesúsLópez I have read about this, and I have actually tried with temporary table. The result is the same. It seems actually after turning on the live statistics that it does clustered index scan...

Comment: Could you please post the execution plan? You may want to use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. And please, show the index and table definitions.

Comment: @JesúsLópez Thanks for tips, did not know about that site! I have added all the information

Comment: Create an index on your temp table, with both column included.

Comment: @Alex I'll try tomorrow, thanks for help, will it hint the planner to the right index?

Comment: SQL Server costs random IO very high, and I assume you are either on SSD or have the whole table in memory. So it thinks the Key Lookups are expensive, which you can se from the plan 99% estimated cost

Comment: I suggest you to change the title of your question to "why Sql Server is choosing the “wrong” Index?" because "how to investigate" requires a very long answer and it is not appropriate to SO. The same thing about "what I can do to figure it out ..."

Comment: @JesúsLópez Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for whatever reason Sql Server choses
> IX_SiloId_ChangedTime_IncludeTime

That is not what the execution plan says. SQL Server chooses `PK_Transaction` clustered index when no index hint is specified.

It is clear to me why SQL Server chooses `PK_Transaction` instead of `IX_SiloId_Time_IncludeContent` when looking at the execution plans. The reason is **poor cardinality estimates**. Both execution plans show that SQL Server estimates that the join operation produces 2.5182.000 rows, but it actually produces 4.155 rows. If SQL Server chooses `IX_SiloId_Time_IncludeContent` then it estimates that it needs to perform 2.5182.000 key lookups. With 2.5182.000 key lookups using `IX_SiloId_Time_IncludeContent` index the plan is more expensive than a plan with hash match and clustered index scan. If SQL Server was able to estimate better, it would choose `IX_SiloId_Time_IncludeContent` because with only 4.155 key lookups the plan is much less costly.

So, what can you do?. I think on two options:

- Include the index hint. Index hints exist for a reason. Poor cardinality estimates is a good reason to include the hint.
- Try with the covering index suggested by the first execution plan. With  covering indexes, no key lookups are needed. So it is very likely that SQL Server chooses the covering index.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a good answer, that sheds some light on what is going on. Covering index would require the whole table really, and while I can do that it seems like an overkill. I don't really know why the estimate is so much off..., would be nice to figure that one out as well :) I did run update statistics right before that

Comment: Regarding the wrong index: when I did the query for only 1 element it chose the wrong index, but it took forever with 1000 and I did not know that I can see the "live" plan, that is why the confusion, sorry about that :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik getting precise estimates is very very hard. It's based on statistics that are based on samples. Some conditions can lead to good estimates. But the condition `t.Time >= q.Time` is very hard to get a good estimate.

Comment: I have added index on temp table, it did not help unfortunately, but interestingly enough the option FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION  helped and the estimate was correct! Don't really know what should I make with it, weird to have such things in a query

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik, yes legacy cardinality estimation is more optimistic (less estimated rows), but it is worse in average. That doesn't mean legacy cardinality estimation could be better in some cases

Comment: It looks like I am kind of out of options here and have to force the index though?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik,  both index hint and cardinality estimation hint are valid, just add a comment saying why you are using the hint.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll stick with the index option

Comment: It really seems that you are very right that this condition `t.Time >= q.Time` is very hard to estimate. It seems it does not have good stats not on temp table nor on TVP. If time is hardcoded, the estimates are very correct. But here it seems the estimate that there will be just random dates or something (even though all 1000 rows have the same date in my example)

Comment: I have even created an ordinary table with indexes just to try it out, and SQL Server still estimates orders of magnitude more than it should

Comment: What indexes?. (SiloId, Time)  would be the best. Have you tried to create statistics on (SiloId, Time) and just (Time)? I believe that SQL Server cardinality estimator falls back to harcoded guesses when the estimation process gets very hard.

Comment: I tried SiloId, Time and just Time and primary on SiloId... So I suppose you are right and it just falls back to some hardcoded guesses. Though considering I had just 1 distinct value of time in the whole table that I created for test that is a bit strange

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik, I agree with you, but it is what it is. SQL Server cardinality estimator is not perfect because it's very hard, but it is good enough, that is why hints exist. And you have a good enough solution for your performance problem helping query processor with a good hint.

Comment: Seems like it :) Thanks a lot for you help, it's much clearer now for me what's going on and I have a working workaround which is always good!